# How to add accessibility modifier to Text View using extension in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have no clue. This is what I wrote. I know it's a futile attempt.

```
struct HelloWorld: View {
  var body: some View {
    Text("Hello, World!")
  }
}

extension Text {
  self.accessibility(hidden: true)
}
```

but I get this error
[image]

UPDATE:
Yes, I guess I can add a function in the extension or implement a struct. But I just want the Text View to inherit the accessibility modifier automatically.

so I can use it like this:

```
var body: some View {
    Text("Hello, World!")
  }
```

This is a struct implementation by @Asperi

```
  //thanks for your answer Asperi, but

  let sayHi = "hi"

  var body: some View {
    List {
      Section(header: HidingAccessibility {Text(self.sayHi)}) {
        Text("Hello, World!")
      }
    }
  }
}

struct HidingAccessibility<Content: View>: View {
  private var content: () -> Content
  init(@ViewBuilder _ content: @escaping () -> Content ) {
    self.content = content
  }

  var body: some View {
    content().accessibility(hidden: true)
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use first variant of answer for `header:`, the second variant is for case when you would want to disable accessibility for, say, entire `List`.

Comment: yes, I would have self all over the place, but I heard Swift is getting rid of the self in the next update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is

```
struct HelloWorld: View {
  var body: some View {
    Text("Hello, World!")
       .hideAccessibility()     // << here !
  }
}

extension Text {
  public func hideAccessibility() -> some View {   // << here !
     self.accessibility(hidden: true)
  }
}
```

or even in more generic way

```
struct HidingAccessibility<Content: View>: View {
    private var content: () -> Content
    init(@ViewBuilder _ content: @escaping () -> Content ) {
        self.content = content
    }

    var body: some View {
        content().accessibility(hidden: true)
    }
}

struct HelloWorld: View { 
  var body: some View {
    HidingAccessibility {
        Text("Hello, World!") // << usual SwiftUI view building here
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I would like to just like the Text view to inherit the modifier. please see my update